# Is it possible to add host entry to /etc/hosts file via Fargate 1.3.0 or 1.4.0?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I need to add host entry to /etc/hosts file via Fargate. And, *extraHosts* via task-definition is not supported with awsvpc. Currently, we are using Fargate 1.3.0 and ready to upgrade to 1.4.0 if the issue can be resolved with 1.4.0.

Also, question asked here - https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/886 suggests it is possible to do via 1.3.0 and 1.4 as well. And, I cannot seem to find either ways.

Can somebody suggest how it can be done?